# how can i access the async and await object properties outside of the function and then display it into a html table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, fetch-api

beginner webdev here

i'm trying to display the relevant random user data as such  in my react component into the below html table by acccessing the properties of the user object, however im not sure how to access them outside of the async function. I'm not even sure if i should be using async here haha. How if at all would i be able to do this?? i even tried making a whole new object insantiator but it wouldn't work.

Thanks!!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const UserTable = () => {
  const API_URl = "https://randomuser.me/api/";

  async function LoadTable() {
    const response = await fetch(API_URl);
    const data = await response.json();
    const person = data.results;
    console.log(person);
    return LoadTable;
  }

  LoadTable();

  return (
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>age</th>
        <th>gender</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  );
};

export default UserTable;
```

Comment: Are you willing to use a library from npm or would you prefer a solution without a library?

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const UserTable = () => {
  const API_URl = "https://randomuser.me/api/";
  // declare state
  const [person, setPerson] = useState(null);

  // call `LoadTable` inside `useEffect` for safety
  useEffect(() => {
    async function LoadTable() {
      const response = await fetch(API_URl);
      const data = await response.json();
      const person = data.results;
      // setState
      setState(person);
    }
    LoadTable();
  }, [])
  
  // do something with `person` down here
  return (
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>age</th>
        <th>gender</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  );
};

export default UserTable;
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that `person` can potentially be `null` where ``do something with `person` down here`` is. It's also good practice to move the definition of `LoadTable` inside the `useEffect` callback, since what is written here violates [the rules of hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks).

Comment: I don't see how does it violates these rules

Comment: If you use `eslint`, it will warn you that you have not included `LoadTable` in array of dependencies. Although `LoadTable` function only dependency is `API_URl` which is a constant. So you may have to 1.disable that eslint rule 2.move LoadTable inside `useEffect` callback 3. use `useCallback` for `LoadTable` 4. Change `LoadTable` so it returns a promise and `onSuccess` or `onError` cases can be handled from the function that calls it. Or other solutions.

Comment: Technically, `LoadTable` is supposed to be listed as a dependency to `useEffect` since it's defined in the body of `UserTable`, but that would defeat the purpose since that would cause the fetch to occur every time the component renders.

Comment: You are right, I'll fix it

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not call `LoadTable` in render. Call it in an event handler or `useEffect`.
2. Store the result in state.
3. Wrap your async functions or functions that may throw an error in a `try catch finally` block.
4. You can store loading state in component state.
5. You can store error in state.
6. Make sure you handle different scenarios and race conditions that may occur.